# Get menu.c32 error when installing esxi

Tags: vmware, bootable-media, esxi, rufus

When booting esxi on USB via rufus, I get a [menu.c32 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBwcr.png), as far as I know, to fix this error, you have to select the yes option.
But after this, I will encounter [connection errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vofP.png) and [failed download errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi7li.png)
I am using rufus version 3.18.1877 which is the latest version now
Can anyone guide me on how to get through this stage?

Rufus Log:

```
Rufus x86 v3.18.1877
Windows version: Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit (Build 19044.1706)
Syslinux versions: 4.07/2013-07-25, 6.04/pre1
Grub versions: 0.4.6a, 2.06
System locale ID: 0x0409 (en-US)
Will use default UI locale 0x0409
SetLGP: Successfully set NoDriveTypeAutorun policy to 0x0000009E
Localization set to 'en-US'
Found USB 2.0 device 'JetFlash Transcend 16GB USB Device' (8564:1000)
NOTE: This device is a USB 3.0 device operating at lower speed...
Using 'autorun.inf' label for drive D: 'HPE-ESXI-6.0.0-UPDATE3-ISO-600.9'
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 16 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 1909, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0xB552CA63
Drive has a Syslinux Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Detected File System: FAT32
  Size: 14.6 GB (15708258304 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Boot: Yes
Unable to send request: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
Scanning image...
ISO analysis:
  Image is an ISO9660 image
  Will use '/isolinux.cfg' for Syslinux
  Detected Syslinux version: 3.86 (from '/isolinux.bin')
Disk image analysis:
  Image does not have a Boot Marker
ISO label: 'ESXI-6.0.0-2494585-STANDARD'  
  Size: 348.3 MB (Projected) 
  Uses: Syslinux/Isolinux v3.86
    With an old menu.c32
  Uses: EFI
Using image: VMware-VMvisor-Installer-6.0.0-2494585.x86_64.iso (348.4 MB)
Checking for Rufus updates...
Checking release channel...
Unable to send request: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
Updates: Unable to access version data
Downloading https://rufus.ie/files/syslinux-4.07/menu.c32
Unable to send request: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
Could not download file - cancelling

Found USB 2.0 device 'JetFlash Transcend 16GB USB Device' (8564:1000)
NOTE: This device is a USB 3.0 device operating at lower speed...
Using 'autorun.inf' label for drive D: 'HPE-ESXI-6.0.0-UPDATE3-ISO-600.9'
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 16 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 1909, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0xB552CA63
Drive has a Syslinux Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Detected File System: FAT32
  Size: 14.6 GB (15708258304 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Boot: Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This not an error, just a notice asking you what you want to do
2. If you want help with a Rufus issue, you need to provide your complete Rufus log, which you can access through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> or by clicking the small Log button left of the `START` button.

**UDATE:** Now that you have posted the log, we can see that the actual error (which intervenes during the download of the file you need, and which the vast majority of people will not have) is: `Unable to send request: The attempt to connect to the server failed`. So there is something on your system which prevents the default Windows networking APIs, which is what Rufus uses, from connecting to the GitHub servers.

Usually, I would tell you to try to connect to that URL using Internet Explorer, because that's a browser that uses the default Windows networking APIs, to confirm that you are getting the same error (and therefore demonstrate that this issue has nothing to do with Rufus), but Microsoft has sunset IE, so you may not be able to do that (and it should be noted that whereas IE has been sunset, the networking APIs haven't, because these are base Windows components that are not directly related to IE). It however looks like your system is configured in a manner that prevents applications from using the basic networking API, and since this is an error that only your system is experiencing, and that a vanilla Windows 10 installation does not, I'm afraid that you will have to figure out how you modified your system from vanilla Windows, to prevent the base Windows 10 networking API from connecting to the internet.

You may want to check that:

- You aren't using a Security Solution that **restricts** the ability of applications like Rufus to download files.
- You aren't behind a firewall that prevents access to https://rufus.ie/files/syslinux-4.07/menu.c32.
- Your network connectivity is working.

If you can't sort any of the above, then [this](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/Usage-Notes#Where_to_manually_copy_the_SyslinuxGRUB_files_if_Rufus_cant_download_them) might interest you, but please note that it is really up to you to sort your network access issues because your networking error does not originate from Rufus and cannot be fixed there (and that is true even if browsers, that use their own networking stack and are usually whitelisted by security solutions, do happen to be able to connect, as it is not reasonable to expect an application like Rufus to include its own multi megabyte custom networking stack, when Windows does provide its own networking stack, which, again, should always work on a vanilla installation of Windows 10).

Comment: This is an error! Because when I select yes I will not be able to bootable USB. And when I select no, when installing on the server, I encounter the message "not com32r image" 
I added log to the main question
thank you

Comment: I'm the developer of Rufus, so I can affirm that this is not an error. Per your log, the error intervenes __after__ you click yes, because your system is preventing the download of the file for some reason. But for most people, the download will work, hence, this is not an error message.